# Is it safe to modify elements inside an enumerate() loop if it is followed by a break?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I've written some python code which loops through a list like below:

```
for idx, r in enumerate(mylist):
    if condition:
        del mylist[idx]
        break
```

My question is, whether it is safe to modify this list inside the loop (like in the above example) as long as I have that break statement? Or should I still be modifying the list outside of the loop?

Comment: @amanb why so? :)

Comment: Yes, that's safe.

Comment: But why? If the loop immediately exits after the modification then I don't understand how that is a problem?

Comment: Your code does **not** iterate over a collection that is mutated. It stops right after the first mutation so the iteration never goes over anything that changes.

Comment: @amanb What kind of side effects?

Comment: It seems this question has divided opinion, I will leave it open for some days to get more views / general consensus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is safe if this code is not concurrent if other threads are not going to use mylist concurrently. But as long as we have [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) I think it safe to do it. Better way is to wrap it in a function and return a new copy this way it will be side effects free

```
def create_my_list(mylist):
  mylist = mylist[:] #to create local copy as mylist is passed by reference
  #mylist is a localcopy here
  for idx, r in enumerate(mylist):
      if condition:
        del mylist[idx]
        break
  return mylist
```

Comment: What is `GIL` ?

Comment: Of course doing it this way has the potential downside of modifying only a single reference to the original list. So if you had other references to the list, they are still going to point to the original, unmodified version, which could lead to subtle bugs

Comment: @NullUserException I cant visualise what you mean. Is my suggestion buggy? My approach was to create a list new each time we need it while not touching the original one

Comment: There is no concurrency, the reason I asked this question is I am not too sure how enumerate() works behind the scenes and whether any issues are caused by modifying the mylist variable inside the loop.  Providing the for loop does not run for another iternation, then am I safe to assume I can always modify the code?

Comment: Your answer is good and I think it is probably right, but the only part of the answer I don't like is the "I think it is safe to do it" part haha, because that is the position I am in right now.  I need something definitive and proven.

Comment: it is internally an iterable enumerate implements `__iter__` and  `__next__` but what I feared earlier is you delete an element lets say before its `[1,2,3]` and you delete 2 it becomes `[1,2]` but it still either will have next or wont  so it wont crash simply it will continue or terminate the loop I can say now definately ;)

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Any code that creates copies of the underlying object instead of modifying it will be susceptible to this kind of bug. Imagine, for example, that you have a list of lists `a`. In some function you create a variable `x = a[i]`, and use this `create_my_list` on `x`. Now `x` will be modified, but `a[i]` (and `a`) will point to the original, unmodified list

Comment: @NullUserException now I get it and will be hard to trace (y) I am trying to learn functional programming erlang they kind of embrace this *do not mutate* and return new to avoid locks my answer had that approach